# How to implement Gray scale morphology to detect round object on gray scale image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology, image-morphology

There are many ways to implement math morph on binary image like imerode and imdilate. Its also used to detect different object/shape using this simple operations on binary image but the problem that i am facing right now is to apply this simple operation i.e erode, dilate and many on grey scale image with out convert them into binary image.

```
Selement = strel('disk',5);//disk type element used in morphology
erodeimage = imerode(image,selement);//this is only implement on binary image
```

Above code is for binary math morph how do i implement same concept on grey scale image.

> Note: If your have any resources regarding gray scale math morph kindly provide it or provide useful link

Comment: `imerode` works on grayscale images. From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html): "IM2 = imerode(IM,SE) erodes the grayscale, binary, or packed binary image IM..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a mathematical morphology (MM) library in MatLab. MM operations on binary images are shown as example/illustration but are performed most of the time as gray level.

I think that the fastest C++ library is [SMIL](https://smil.cmm.mines-paristech.fr/doc/index.html), and you can call it from MatLab. An other fast one in C is [that one](http://www.telecom.ulg.ac.be/research/libmorpho.html) (optimized opening/closing in a single pass).

But if you want to understand a dilation in gray level, here is how it works: for a given pixel **p** you analyze the value of all the pixels in its neighborhood (defined by the structuring element), and you affect to **p** the highest value in the neighborhood. You do it for each pixel in your image. See the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)).

That's in fact a rank filter like the median, but instead of taking the median value, you take the max (or min for the erosion). Obviously that the basic definition and it exits faster algorithms, like the one developed in the library I pointed.